# How to scrape information from one website that need scroll down every time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have one website where I need to scroll down every time to show the information

my code as below, but can not get anything

```
     # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import csv

from parsel import Selector
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 

records=[]

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/stevenqi/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.yaskawa.eu.com/services/robotics-support')
contacts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="icon-close"]')
for contact in  contacts:
    contact.click()
    email=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href,"mailto:")]').get_attribute("href")
    website=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href,"http")]').get_attribute("href")
    Tel=
    records.append((website, email,Tel))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "need to scroll down"? As in, data only loads on the page when you scroll towards some (visible) section? You can make selenium scroll to an element...

Comment: When / why do you need to scroll? Looks like your code is missing too many details here: you need to close accept cookies banner, need to wait for the page to load the contacts, open them etc.

Comment: the webpage have two parts, right part is map, the left side is the company list, which have a scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

I have used another python library [`beautifulsoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) for extracting data from the given website, hope this will be helpful, By using the library you can parse HTML content and extract data on the bases of tags, following is code snippet

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

records = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome("your-chrome-drive-path")
driver.get('https://www.yaskawa.eu.com/services/robotics-support')

    
def partner_name(soup):
    extracted_heading = soup.find("h3")
    _partner_name = str(extracted_heading.text.strip()).replace(extracted_heading.find('i').text, '')
    return _partner_name


def department_name(soup):
    button_text = soup.find("button", class_="accordion__toggle")

    return button_text.text.strip()


def extract_department_info(soup):
    contacts = soup.find('div', class_='contact')
    contact_info = {
        "phone": "",
        "email": "",
        "website": ""
    }
    if contacts:
        href_links = contacts.find_all('a')

        for href_link in href_links:
            if href_link.get('href').startswith('tel'):

                contact_info["phone"] = href_link.text.strip()
            elif href_link.get('href').startswith('mailto'):
                contact_info["email"] = href_link.text.strip()
            else:
                icon_home = href_link.find('i', class_='icon-home')
                if icon_home:
                    contact_info["website"] = href_link.text.strip()
    return contact_info


def extract_contact_info(soup):
    accordion_soup = soup.find('div', class_="accordion")
    contact_info = []

    if accordion_soup:
        departments_contact = accordion_soup.find_all("div", recursive=False)
        for department_contact in departments_contact:
            department = department_name(department_contact)
            extract_info = extract_department_info(department_contact)
            extract_info["department"] = department
            contact_info.append(extract_info)
    return contact_info


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

partners_card = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-partner')
partners_info = []
for partner in partners_card:
    extract_contact_info(partner)
    partners_info.append({"partner": partner_name(partner), "contact": extract_contact_info(partner)})
print(json.dumps(partners_info, indent=4))
```

Following is the output of shared code,

```
[
    {
        "partner": "Yaskawa Europe GmbH ",
        "contact": [
            {
                "phone": "+49 1805 76 26 83",
                "email": "tcs@yaskawa.eu",
                "website": "",
                "department": "Robotics Service Hotline"
            },
            {
                "phone": "+49 8166 90 2005",
                "email": "YEUR-Repair-Sales@yaskawa.eu",
                "website": "",
                "department": "Robotics Repairs"
            },
            {
                "phone": "+49 8166 90 2000",
                "email": "spare-parts-sales@yaskawa.eu",
                "website": "",
                "department": "Robotics Spare Parts"
            },
            {
                "phone": "+49 8166 90 0",
                "email": "tcs-sales@yaskawa.eu",
                "website": "",
                "department": "Robotics Sales for Services"
            },
            {
                "phone": "+49 8166-90-0",
                "email": "robotics@yaskawa.eu",
                "website": "",
                "department": "Robotics Sales"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "partner": "Yaskawa Europe GmbH ",
        "contact": [
            {
                "phone": "+49 6196 569 300",
                "email": "",
                "website": "https://www.yaskawa.eu.com/lp/contacts",
                "department": "Contact"
            },
            {
                "phone": "+ 49 6196 569 500",
                "email": "support@yaskawa.eu.com",
                "website": "",
                "department": "Drives Motion Support"
            },
            {
                "phone": "+49 9132 744 1150",
                "email": "support@yaskawa.eu.com",
                "website": "",
                "department": "Controls Support (VIPA)"
            }
        ]
    },
# Reduced number of lines just to show raw output
    {
        "partner": "ZyTECH Innovative Solutions ",
        "contact": [
            {
                "phone": "+598-2-901 3311",
                "email": "info@zytech.com.uy",
                "website": "www.zytech.com.uy",
                "department": "Contact"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

bs4 can extract data based on HTML tags, classes, attributes, and so on. Hope this will help you.